# Meaning of initial-scale = 1.0

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What is the exact meaning of 'initial-scale=1.0' in the meta tag? How is it useful? How does it make a difference if we donot use it?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 2):

> `initial-scale` is the initial zoom when visiting a page. **A value of
>   1.0 does not zoom.**

Good explanations on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: What does "zoom" mean in this context? I'm trying different initial-scale values but they look all the same in a desktop Firefox and Chrome, nothing is zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

> A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.
>
> The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
>
> The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Comment: Thank You @keziah I saw the above definitions in w3schools. I want a deeper understanding of initial-scale = 1.0 statement. What does it exactly mean and how does it exactly work?

Answer (score 1):

The default value of initial-scale (mapped to the `@viewport` rule `zoom` property) is "auto". Browsers may take "intelligent" guesses at what scale to use, which might work out well or not. Different browsers guess in different ways. Setting the initial-scale to 1.0 should stop that guessing.